# ElasticSearch - field type timerange?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible to have field type that would look like List>?
So I have Java POJOs:

```
 public class Document {
//omitted other fields
private List<ChildDocument> values;

class ChildDocument {
    private List<String> words;
    private Timerange timerange;
}

class Timerange {
    // time in format "10:15:30.222"
    // LocalTime from Java-8 time api
    private LocalTime start;
    private LocalTime end;
}
```

}

Example data in such field:

```
index -> {time-range -> list of strings}
(0) -> "08:00:00.000 - 09:00:00.000" -> {"1", "2", "3"}
(1) -> "11:00:00.000 - 13:00:00.000" -> {"4", "5", "6"}
```

And I would query "find 'time-range' that has '5' in it" and I would get "08:00:00.000 - 09:00:00.00" as property defined as in my Java ChildDocument. Is it possible to store in ES just time-range without dates? And do this kind of nested objects?  I know I cound store that TimeRange field as String and parse it back in my Java app but trying to optimize it so ES does most of the work.

Still new to ES (came from Solr and that's impossible there).

Comment: You can use the nested data type in ES https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/nested.html

Comment: The nested type will retain the time range/words relationship but you will be storing time stamps or you can use string depending on your use case